# User memory limit exceeded

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, otsu

I made this module to apply Otsu Thresholding and canny edge to generate pure pixel values and to save memory, however when I call this module to main script using;
var otsu = require (path/modlule_name);

Module code given here:
'''

```
// Define the module function
function applyCannyAndOtsu(image_with_indices, geometry) {
  // Canny edge filter with a high threshold applied to the spectral index image reveals only edges located near sharp value changes
  var mndwi = image_with_indices.select('mndwi');
  var edge = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector({
    image: mndwi,
    threshold: 0.99,
    sigma: 0.7
  }).mask().lt(0.8).connectedPixelCount(30, true).gte(30);

  var im = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
    mndwi.visualize({
      min: -0.5,
      max: 0.5,
      palette: ['ffffff', '000000']
    }),
    edge.focal_max(1).mask(edge.focal_max(1)).visualize({ palette: ['ff0000'] })
  ]).mosaic();

  // Create a buffer around the mndwi edge pixels
  var mndwi_buffer = mndwi.updateMask(mndwi.mask()).mask(edge.focal_max(30, 'square', 'meters'));

  im = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
    ee.Image(1).visualize({ palette: ["ffffff"] }),
    mndwi_buffer.visualize({ min: -0.5, max: 0.5, palette: ["ffffff", "000000"] })
  ]).mosaic().clip(geometry);

  // Create a histogram of the pixel values in the buffer image.
  var histogram = mndwi_buffer.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram(255),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9,
    bestEffort: true
  });

  // Get the threshold value using the Otsu method.
  function otsu(histogram) {
    histogram = ee.Dictionary(histogram);

    var counts = ee.Array(histogram.get('histogram'));
    var means = ee.Array(histogram.get('bucketMeans'));
    var size = means.length().get([0]);
    var total = counts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
    var sum = means.multiply(counts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
    var mean = sum.divide(total);

    var indices = ee.List.sequence(1, size);

    // Compute between sum of squares, where each mean partitions the data.
    var bss = indices.map(function(i) {
      var aCounts = counts.slice(0, 0, i);
      var aCount = aCounts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
      var aMeans = means.slice(0, 0, i);
      var aMean = aMeans.multiply(aCounts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]).divide(aCount);
      var bCount = total.subtract(aCount);
      var bMean = sum.subtract(aCount.multiply(aMean)).divide(bCount);
      return aCount.multiply(aMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)).add(bCount.multiply(bMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)));
    });

    // Return the mean value corresponding to the maximum BSS.
    return means.sort(bss).get([-1]);
  }

  var threshold_water = otsu(histogram.get('mndwi'));
  print('Water Threshold:', threshold_water);

  // Binarize the Canny edge image using the threshold value.
  var water = mndwi.gt(threshold_water);
  var pure_water = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector(water, threshold_water, 0);

  var final_water = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
    image_with_indices.visualize({ min: 0.05, max: 0.5, bands: ['swir2', 'nir', 'r'] }),
    water.mask(water).visualize({ opacity: 0.6, palette: ['43a2ca'] }),
    pure_water.mask(pure_water).visualize({ palette: ['ffffff'] }),
  ]).mosaic().clip(geometry);

  // ******** Section 5 - Applying Canny edge and Otsu thresholding to get pure veg pixels  ******//

  // Canny edge filter with a high threshold applied to the spectral index image reveals only edges located near sharp value changes
  var ndvi = image_with_indices.select('ndvi');
  var ndvi_edge = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector({
    image: ndvi,
    threshold: 0.3,
    sigma: 0.1
  }).mask().lt(0.8).connectedPixelCount(30, true).gte(30);

  var im = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
    ndvi.visualize({
      min: -0.5,
      max: 0.5,
      palette: ['ffffff', '000000']
    }),
    ndvi_edge.focal_max(1).mask(ndvi_edge.focal_max(1)).visualize({ palette: ['ff0000'] })
  ]).mosaic();

  // Create a buffer around the ndvi edge pixels
  var ndvi_buffer = ndvi.updateMask(ndvi.mask()).mask(ndvi_edge.focal_max(30, 'square', 'meters'));

  im = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
    ee.Image(1).visualize({ palette: ["ffffff"] }),
    ndvi_buffer.visualize({ min: -0.5, max: 0.5, palette: ["ffffff", "000000"] })
  ]).mosaic().clip(geometry);

  // Create a histogram of the pixel values in the buffer image.
  var histogram = ndvi_buffer.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram(255),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9,
    bestEffort: true
  });

  var threshold_veg = otsu(histogram.get('ndvi'));
  print('Vegetation Threshold:', threshold_veg);

  // Binarize the Canny edge image using the threshold value.
  var veg = ndvi.gt(threshold_veg);
  var pure_veg = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector(veg, threshold_veg, 0);

  var final_veg = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
    image_with_indices.visualize({ min: 0.05, max: 0.5, bands: ['swir2', 'nir', 'r'] }),
    veg.mask(veg).visualize({ opacity: 0.6, palette: ['008000'] }),
    pure_veg.mask(pure_veg).visualize({ palette: ['ffffff'] }),
  ]).mosaic().clip(geometry);
  
  
  
  
 // Canny edge filter with a high threshold applied to the spectral index image reveals only edges located near sharp value changes
  var bsi = image_with_indices.select('bsi');
  var bsi_edge = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector({
    image: bsi,
    threshold: 0.26,
    sigma: 0.4
  }).mask().lt(0.8).connectedPixelCount(30, true).gte(30);

  var im = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
    bsi.visualize({
      min: -0.5,
      max: 0.5,
      palette: ['ffffff', '000000']
    }),
    bsi_edge.focal_max(1).mask(bsi_edge.focal_max(1)).visualize({ palette: ['ff0000'] })
  ]).mosaic();

  // Create a buffer around the bsi edge pixels
  var bsi_buffer = bsi.updateMask(bsi.mask()).mask(bsi_edge.focal_max(30, 'square', 'meters'));

  im = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
    ee.Image(1).visualize({ palette: ["ffffff"] }),
    bsi_buffer.visualize({ min: -0.5, max: 0.5, palette: ["ffffff", "000000"] })
  ]).mosaic().clip(geometry);

  // Create a histogram of the pixel values in the buffer image.
  var histogram = bsi_buffer.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram(255),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9,
    bestEffort: true
  });

  var threshold_soil = otsu(histogram.get('bsi'));
  print('soil Threshold:', threshold_soil);

  // Binarize the Canny edge image using the threshold value.
  var soil = bsi.gt(threshold_soil);
  var pure_soil = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector(soil, threshold_soil, 0);

  var final_soil = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
    image_with_indices.visualize({ min: 0.05, max: 0.5, bands: ['swir2', 'nir', 'r'] }),
    soil.mask(soil).visualize({ opacity: 0.6, palette: ['FFEFD5'] }),
    pure_soil.mask(pure_soil).visualize({ palette: ['ffffff'] }),
  ]).mosaic().clip(geometry);
  
  return {
    final_water: final_water,
    final_veg: final_veg,
    final_soil: final_soil
  };
}


// Export the module function and specify the required inputs
exports.applyCannyAndOtsu = applyCannyAndOtsu;
```

'''
It give me values and map for for water and vegetation but not for bare soil.
For soil it gives Layer error: User memory limit exceeded.

I use the code given below to call the module into main code:
'''

```
var OtsuModule = require('users/path:OtsuModule');

// Apply the OtsuModule function
var results = OtsuModule.applyCannyAndOtsu(image_with_indices, geometry);
// Access the results
var final_water = results.final_water;
var final_veg = results.final_veg;
var final_soil = results.final_soil;

// Add the layers to the map
Map.addLayer(final_water, {}, 'Water');
Map.addLayer(final_veg, {}, 'Vegetation');
Map.addLayer (final_soil, {}, 'Soil');

var water = final_water;
var veg = final_veg;
var soil = final_soil;
```

'''

Can anyone help in solving this issue?

[image]